# Is there a reason to ever use s String interpolation over f String interpolation?

Tags: scala, string-formatting, string-interpolation

Scala's f-strings seem to have the exact same functionality as s-strings, the only difference being that f-string variables *should* end with a printf-style format string, like `%d`.

But the `%` format string isn't required, and the typesafe feature of the f interpolator isn't used without the `%`.

So why do s-strings exist when f-strings seem strictly better(and more similar to python f-strings)?

Comment: http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStylePrincipleofLeastPower.html

Comment: @SethTisue so seeing an f-string I should assume it has `%` format string(s) in it, even though there might not be?  Likewise, if I create an f-string without `%` formatters I'm writing bad code since other devs will assume there's `%` formatters?

Comment: yes, that's my thinking on this.